# Proposal to close flight price search questions

Tags: discussion

We've had some like - what airlines or LCCs fly from X to Y. This seems like a genuine travel question that can benefit others.

However, we have also had some (currently unanswered ones) about pricing:

[How can I book the plane schedule I want from the USA to Japan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18142/how-can-i-book-the-plane-schedule-i-want-from-the-usa-to-japan)

[Cheapest way to fly one-way from Lima, Peru to Brazil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17827/cheapest-way-to-fly-one-way-from-lima-peru-to-brazil)

I don't mean to pick on anyone, we've had several of these in the past, but I feel we should start closing them as too localised.

- The flights are very specific, often including specific airlines and dates
- They're very unlikely to be of use to future visitors to the site
- We're a Q&A site, not a travel agent.  We provide travel answers, from knowledge / research.
- Flight prices fluctuate on a daily, sometimes hourly basis.  Any answer that IS provided / accepted is almost certainly going to be wrong a few days later.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with Mark. We don't even need a new special rule because, as Mark said, they are **too localized**.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, these types of questions have received answers or at least some help, so there's some value in keeping (some of) them.

I'd say, don't close them right away as they pop up, but allow a week or two for a reasonable answer, and if none appears, close or flag them. These questions tend to linger in the unanswered pile, so finding them later is easy.

Comment: I'm not fussed on historic ones. We have lots of historic questions that would likely be closed if asked these days.
My concern is encouraging this type of question. In particular for the last two reasons I provided above - most important of which, the answers are likely to be inaccurate.